# Unity doesn't resolve with Admob

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, admob

I am trying to add admob to my unity game, but the resolve step is not working
PS:I am using a project provided by google to try admob so the problem isn't from the project.

I am using unity 5.0.2f1 and i downloaded [this ad sample project](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/tree/master/samples/HelloWorld) but the ads were not showing.
after some trial and error i tried to resolve, which gave me the error 
"Gradle failed to fetch dependencies"
"Failed To Resolve"

This is the error description:

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'C:\Users\owner\Desktop\HelloWorld\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat -b "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\HelloWorld\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" --no-daemon "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/AndroidSDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=C:\Users\owner\Desktop\HelloWorld\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0"'
stdout:
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-bin.zip


stderr:
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.util.AnchorCertificates.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.checkFingerprint(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.AlgorithmChecker.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.isTrusted(JarVerifier.java:610)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:530)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:363)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:289)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:164)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:190)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.canUseProvider(JceSecurity.java:204)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(KeyAgreement.java:179)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce$EcAvailability.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:55)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:55)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.getCacertsKeyStore(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.getTrustManagers(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:103)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:757)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1D:<>m__3A(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/ResolverVer1_1.cs:849)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1F:<>m__48() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/ResolverVer1_1.cs:922)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__16() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
Google.RunOnMainThread:Run(Action, Boolean) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:363)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1D:<>m__3B(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/ResolverVer1_1.cs:922)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:SignalComplete() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:116)
GooglePlayServices.ProgressReporter:CommandLineToolCompletion(Result) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLineDialog.cs:107)
GooglePlayServices.<RunAsync>c__AnonStorey2:<>m__4() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/PlayServicesResolver/src/CommandLine.cs:136)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:377)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAll>m__16() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:408)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction(Action) (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:234)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll() (at /Users/smiles/dev/src/unity-jar-resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:406)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Lost hope and got a new pc and upgraded to unity 2019.1.8f1
Ads now work

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your Java version doesn't have a compatible root certificate, or use a default SSL version, that allows you to download gradle from https://services.gradle.org. Unfortunately, depending on which gradle is needed and which Java version you have, you may need to switch between JDKs. As a general rule of thumb, it's best to keep up with modern version of JDK as long as you do not have legacy software that requires an old one.

You can switch between JDKs in Unity from Edit > Preferences > External Tools.

Hope this helps someone in the future without needing to buy a whole computer! ;)